# How much installed nginx weight (without installed applications)

Tags: nginx, server

I was wondering, how much installed nginx (without any application installed in it) is directory size. And how is it compared to Apache and IIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installed size depends on a distro and specific compilation options used for each software. RHEL 8 example:

NGINX: 2.9 M

Apache: 4.8 M